# Passing a variable value from one class to another class in java

Tags: java, getter-setter

I have this Java program where I take a user's input for length and width and calculate the total area and perimeter. Per the exercise instructions it uses two classes, Main and Rectangle. The problem I have is I don't know how to pass the length and width values from the main class to the Rectangle class. When I run the program it just gives me zero values and tells me that the local variables (length and width) within the Main class aren't used.  I can only use a zero-argument constructor in the Rectangle class because that's what the exercise calls for. I know how to make the program work by using a different constructor that accepts two arguments (length and width). I have google searched and looked throughout this forum but I still can't figure this out. Can someone give me some hints, thanks.

**Here is the Main class.**

```
package murach.rectangle;

import java.util.Scanner; 
import murach.rectangle.Rectangle;



public class Main {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Area and Perimeter Calculator");
    System.out.println();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = "y";
    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
        // get input from user
        System.out.print("Enter length: ");
        double length = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Enter width:  ");
        double width = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();

        String message = 
            "Area:         " +  rectangle.getAreaNumberFormat() + "\n" +
            "Perimeter:    " + rectangle.getPerimeterNumberFormat() + "\n";
        System.out.println(message);

        // see if the user wants to continue
        System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
        choice = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
    }
    sc.close();
    System.out.println("Bye!");
  }
}
```

**Here is the Rectangle class.**

```
package murach.rectangle;

import java.text.NumberFormat; 

public class Rectangle {


  private double width;
  private double length;


  public Rectangle() {
    width = 0;
    length = 0;
  }


  public double getWidth() {
    return width;
  }

  public void setWidth(double width) {
    this.width = width;
  }
  public double getLength() {
    return length;
  }
  public void setLength(double length) {
    this.length = length;
  }
  public double getArea() { 
    double area = length * width;
    return area;
  }
  public double getPerimeter() {
    double perimeter = 2 * width + 2 * length;
    return perimeter;
  }
  public String getAreaNumberFormat() {
    NumberFormat number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    number.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
    String numberAreaFormatted = number.format(width);
    return numberAreaFormatted;
  }
  public String getPerimeterNumberFormat() {
    NumberFormat number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    number.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
    String numberPerimeterFormatted = number.format(length);
    return numberPerimeterFormatted;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call your setters to update the fields:

```
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
rectangle.setLength(length);
rectangle.setWidth(width);
```

Side note: "height" is more conventional and less ambiguous a term than "length".

Comment: I guess "height" is used for 3 dimensional objects representing the third dimension. Otherwise, all 2D structures IMO go with length and breadth (or width)

Comment: @PavanKumar I would probably go with height, width and depth. But I'm no experienced with 3D objects, to be honest.

Comment: I have another question. I changed the program back to where it uses a different constructor in the Rectangle class that accepts the two arguments (length and width) and then modified Main so it uses that constructor instead of the zero argument one. I found the actual solution for this exercise and includes an import statement in the Rectangle class (import murach.rectangle.Rectangle). What is this used for? My program works fine with or without this import statement.

Comment: Also the third lines in the getAreaNumberFormat and getPerimeterNumberFormat methods had to be corrected to: String numberFormatted = number.format(getArea()); and String numberFormatted = number.format(getPerimeter());, however the solution added a "this" to the statements numberFormatted = number.format(this.getArea()); and numberFormatted = number.format(this.getPerimeter()); Why use "this", the program works with or without it.

Comment: You should be able to answer those questions with a little research. If you're still stuck, post them as new questions.